# post facebook feed on Flash AIR Desktop using AS3

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, air

I need to share Facebook feed using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed`, so I searching and researching until I stumble upon FacebookGraphAPIDesktop.swc. But I failed to login, I already populate the required field (APP_ID, APP_ORIGIN) and make an adjustment on facebook app page too (App Domains & Site URL).

I already init the FacebookDesktop class and try to make a login connection using

```
        var permissions:Array = ["email"];
        FacebookDesktop.login(onLogin, permissions);
```

But it show popup windows contain JSON `Invalid redirect_uri, OAuthException, code: 191`

Any direction for dong this? bassically I need to show facebook OAUTH login popup and show feed dialog after the login success.

The environment is Flash AIR 17 running on Desktop (not mobile)

Answer (score 0):

When working with Facebook for desktop and not using your own backend servers for login support, set the redirect URI to to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

If you are using your own servers, then the redirect URI should be set to the page that is going to handle the response from Facebook.

In either case, you will need to make sure that you log in to your app on the Facebook developer portal and set the app settings for desktop login and set that redirect URI in there.